# Nextjs Nested Dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

`http://localhost:3000/category/leadership/expert`

`http://localhost:3000/category/topics/technology/business-tech-blogs`

I have category routes like this. and current file looks like this `pages/category/[...slug].js`. Its using ISR and working without a problem.

Now I need a route for feed page for each of these route.
Example

`http://localhost:3000/category/leadership/expert/feed`

`http://localhost:3000/category/topics/technology/business-tech-blogs/feed`

How can define file for this. This will be SSR as ISR does not support `xml` content.

I tried `pages/category/[slug]/[...params].js` and it works but then it breaks my category page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new route. The only thing you need to do is check the last param, and if it is `feed` you render your Feed page.

The code would look like this

```
const Category = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { params } = router.query;

  const lastParam = Array.isArray(params) ? [...params].pop() : null;

  if (lastParam === 'feed') {
    return (
      <span>
        Feed Page
      </span>
    );
  }

  return (
    <span>
      Category Page
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: This will not work as my ```feed``` page needs to be SSR.